# Configure a p2 update repository programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, p2

There is an article in the Eclipse wiki how to configure user's p2 default repositories of an RCP application by adding a static conf file to your product:

[Equinox/p2/Adding Self-Update to an RCP Application - Configuring the user's default repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application#Configuring_the_user.27s_default_repositories)

I want to do the same programmatically in a Java class when the user changes some configuration details. I could not find appropriate p2 API documentation for that.

Comment: Did you check the latest P2 API presentation? (not sure if it helps in your case though): http://www.slideshare.net/PascalRapicault/discovering-the-p2-api

Comment: There are 3 lines of code in this presentation - no more API documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. It's easy - unfortunately there is no documentation...

```
    // from bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.console
    import org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.console.ProvisioningHelper;

    URI repoUri = new URI(UPDATE_SITE_URL);
    try {
        ProvisioningHelper.addMetadataRepository(repoUri);         
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        LOG.warn("Can not add update repository: " + repoUri);           
    }
    try {
        ProvisioningHelper.addArtifactRepository(repoUri);          
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        LOG.warn("Can not add update repository: " + repoUri);
    }
```

Comment: methods of ProvisioningHelper class are internal. Not accessible out side :(

Answer (score 4):

Use this solution for Eclipse 3.7 based applications:

```
final ProvisioningUI ui = ProvUIActivator.getDefault().getProvisioningUI();
IArtifactRepositoryManager artifactManager = ProvUI.getArtifactRepositoryManager(ui.getSession());
artifactManager.addRepository(new URI(UPDATE_SITE_URL);

IMetadataRepositoryManager metadataManager = ProvUI.getMetadataRepositoryManager(ui.getSession());
metadataManager.addRepository(new URI(UPDATE_SITE_URL);
```

For *ProvUI* and *ProvisioningUI* you have to import bundles *org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui* and *org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations* (among others).

Comment: Thnaks, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Furthermore you can add more than one repositories with ElementUtils and also you can sort them.

```
MetadataRepositoryElement[] element = new MetadataRepositoryElement[links.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        element[i] = new MetadataRepositoryElement(null, new URI(links[i]), true);
        element[i].setNickname("Link-"+i);
    }
    ElementUtils.updateRepositoryUsingElements(element, null);
```

These links will be appeared alphabetically sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This is high on the Google query for this issue, and there's still not a good way to do it published:

If anyone finds this page via Google as I did, I've solved this problem.  You can use org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.ElementUtils.updateRepositoryUsingElements to set the repositories programmatically.  Full code can be found [here.](http://coopology.com/2012/08/eclipse-rcp-setting-p2-repositories-update-sites-programmatically-for-when-p2-inf-fails/)